# Не работает transition (background) в Firefox

Tags: firefox, hover, background, transition

Цель: при наведении на фото изменить другим

Проблема: transition для свойства background не работает в Mozilla Firefox

```css
.photo {
    background: url("image/photos/KoretsW1.jpg") no-repeat fixed 50% 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.photo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url("image/photos/KoretsW2.jpg") no-repeat fixed 50% 100%;
}
```

Или же раньше было свойство background-image, но оказалось что по спецификации W3C свойство background-image не является анимируемым.

Можете посмотреть на сайте: workout.korets.in.ua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ясно в чем вопрос, но если "как имитировать?", то:

```css
.photo {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 600px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photo_bg,
.photo_bg__hover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
          transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.photo_bg {
  background-image: url('http://workout.korets.in.ua/image/photos/KoretsW1.jpg');
}

.photo_bg__hover {
  background-image: url("http://workout.korets.in.ua/image/photos/KoretsW2.jpg");
  opacity: 0;
}

.photo:hover .photo_bg {
    opacity: 0;
}

.photo:hover .photo_bg__hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <div class="photo_bg"></div>
  <div class="photo_bg__hover"></div>
</div>
```